# Cloth Physics Similar to Sheet Metal

Tags: physics, cloth-simulation

I am looking for an explanation of to create a cloth physics that acts like sheet metal. I am a Maya user trying to wrap my head around the Blender workflow. I have been struggling with simulating this type of substance; I cannot seem to get the object stiff enough. Can someone help me with creating a sheet metal cloth simulation?

Thanks!

Comment: More info could help others to understand what you are looking for: 1) reference video of a real sheet metal, if you are using it, 2) your maya setup for that... 3) a maya animation you did before, showing the effect you wish to replicate...